# Mysql file is not linking to python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
import sqlite3


def ConnectData():
    con = sqlite3.connect("libbooks.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libbooks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, MTy text, Ref text, Title text,
                   Fna text, Sna text, Adr1 text, Adr2 text, Pcd text, MNo text, BkID text, BkT text, Atr text, 
                   DBo text, Ddu text, sPr text, Lrf text, Dod text, DonL text''')
    con.commit()
    con.close()


def addDataRec(MTy, Ref, Title,Fna, Sna, Adr1, Adr2, Pcd, MNo, BkID, BkT, Atr, DBo , Ddu, sPr, Lrf, Dod, DonL):
    con = sqlite3.connect("libbooks.db")

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO libbooks VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                (MTy, Ref, Title,Fna, Sna, Adr1, Adr2, Pcd, MNo, BkID, BkT, Atr, DBo, Ddu, sPr, Lrf, Dod, DonL))
    con.commit()
    con.close()


ConnectData()
```

The error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Python
> Projects\Test1\GUI\LMS.py", line 3, in 
> import LibBksDatabase   File "D:\Python Projects\Test1\GUI\LibBksDatabase.py", line 23, in 
> ConnectData()   File "D:\Python Projects\Test1\GUI\LibBksDatabase.py", line 7, in ConnectData
> cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libbooks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, MTy text, Ref text, Title text, sqlite3.OperationalError:
> incomplete input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you need to tell the interpreter that the statement continues on the next line.

Add a

```
\
```

at the end of a line to continue the statement on the next line.
In your case:

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libbooks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, MTy text, Ref text, Title text, \
                   Fna text, Sna text, Adr1 text, Adr2 text, Pcd text, MNo text, BkID text, BkT text, Atr text, \
                   DBo text, Ddu text, sPr text, Lrf text, Dod text, DonL text''')
```

Let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace.

`DonL text` --> `DonL text)`

the code below works:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("libbooks.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libbooks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, MTy text, Ref text, Title text,
               Fna text, Sna text, Adr1 text, Adr2 text, Pcd text, MNo text, BkID text, BkT text, Atr text, 
               DBo text, Ddu text, sPr text, Lrf text, Dod text, DonL text)''')
con.commit()
con.close()
```